# Copy Multiple text into HTML Form area, processed with Python

Tags: php, python, html, forms

I have the following simple HTML Form, which then is passed to PHP as post action.

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="final.php" method="post">

Member: <input type="text" name="Member"><br>
Identifier: <input type="text" name="Identifier"><br>
Phone Number: <input type="text" name="Number"><br>
Phone Terminal Nr. : <input type="text" name="terminal"><br>

<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The Output is something like this:

```
********
Jon Doe
********


This is Member Jon Doe
With Identifier JD567890
Member Phone: 555-789-999

Phone Terminal Nr.: 1

....
```

In this example over the year, Member Jon Doe adds more Phone numbers, every Phone Number gets its own Phone Terminal Number.
So the next would be :

```
********
Jon Doe
********


This is Member Jon Doe
With Identifier JD567890
Member Phone: 555-129-223


Phone Terminal Nr.: 2
```

Every Number has to be copy and pasted one by one.
I would like the ability to paste multiple number all at once in the Member Phone Area and the also atomatically assign the next Phone Terminal Nr incremental to each individual Phone Terminal in the output: something like this:

```
********
Jon Doe
********

This is Member Jon Doe
With Identifier JD567890

Member Phone: 555-129-223
Phone Terminal Nr.: 2

Member Phone: 555-129-986
Phone Terminal Nr.: 3

Member Phone: 555-129-234
Phone Terminal Nr.: 4

Member Phone: 555-129-244
Phone Terminal Nr.: 5

Member Phone: 555-129-275
Phone Terminal Nr.: 6

Member Phone: 555-129-527
Phone Terminal Nr.: 7

Member Phone: 555-166-220
Phone Terminal Nr.: 8
```

Would like to do this in python, cause Im learning it, maybe its easier in Javascript or PHP, so Im all ears of advice.
Since I dont know how many Numbers I can get a day (sometimes 10, 15, 8, 30 numers etc.., So I dont know how to approach this using Lists
And the tricky part for me is the Incremental number

here is my PHP script as reference which I would Like to convert to Python with the above requierements:

```
<html>
<body>
<h6>
<br><br>

;*********************************************************************************<br>
;  <?php echo $_POST["Member"]; ?><br>
;*********************************************************************************<br><br>


This is Member <?php echo $_POST["Member"]; ?><br>
With Identifier <?php echo $_POST["Identifier"]; ?><br>
Member Phone: <?php echo $_POST["Number"]; ?>

<br><br><br>

Phone Terminal Nr.: <?php echo $_POST["terminal"]; ?>

<br><br><br>
```

Comment: Your PHP code currently doesn't handle multiple phone numbers, right? BTW what have you already tried in Python? Could you edit your question to add your Python code to it, please?

Comment: Hi Gustavo, No as you can see the actuall PHP code only handles one by one. I want some guideness because Im new to Python on how to approach this. Maybe someone says I should stick to the PHP I allready have and forget the Python route, which maybe (not sure) is way more complicated. Sorry dont have python code to share...

Comment: As I said,  I was thinking about to create Lists or variables for each number, But sometimes I get different quantity of numbers so i dont know how to create this storage of unknown quantity numbers.

Comment: Short answer: You need a database for this. There you have a table `User` and a table `Number`, and the `Number` has a field like `userID`, so you know to whom it belongs. You can do this f.e. With a MySQL Database. There are tons of examples about PHP and MySQL, so you should be able to find something.

Comment: I know that with a Database this could be resolved, But I dont need to track back user IDs..Basicaly I need to be able to copy eg 8 numbers inside the text area type in the first Terminal Nr. example 56 and get an text output with Numbers pasted + the incremented  terminal nr. Does it make sense? just simple. nothing has to be stored. it is allready been stored in a database where there is no access to it. we get an email with those numbers and the terminal id

Comment: I nearly found a way...

Comment: I nearly found a way... Its using PHP explode function, but, what I dont know is how can I handle different input quantities (sometimes I have to process 10 or 15 or 20 PhoneNumbers so its not always a fixed number to process) ,once I process the input string into chunks using explode into array